# Solving the rate limit exception with tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm using `tweepy` to scrap twitter. I need to fetch the entire followers of a user but of course I get a rate limit exception. I saw that i should use the `Cursor` object to iterate through all the friends/followers of a user. But is there any possibility to select a range of pages? So on one day I get the data of page 1-10 then in the next day the next 10 page ... etc. Is that possible? or is there a different trick to get over the rate limit thing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use `tweepy`, but when you query a list with the Twitter API and this list is incomplete, the JSON object returned by the Twitter API comes with the attribute `next_cursor` set to a value different than zero.

All you have to do is repeat that query including a param `cursor` in the POST request with the value of `next_cursor` that you got in the last one and repeat the process until `next_cursor` comes 0.

By the way, [according to the documentation](https://support.twitter.com/groups/56-policies-violations/topics/237-guidelines/articles/160385-twitter-api-limits#), you are allowed to do up to 350 requests **per hour** to the Twitter API, so you don't really have to wait until the next day. I suppose you can workaround this limit if you have multiple IP addresses.